# How to get contenttype options in Bolt CMS

Tags: bolt-cms

I have contenttype for products:

```
products_de:
    name: Products (de)
    singular_name: Product (de)
    slug: produkte
    singular_slug: produkt
    tablename: products_de
    fields:
        ...
```

I've set slug for german site version links. But how I can get contenttype slug from my template? I need it automaticly, because I want to add contenttype `products_en` with slug `products` for english site version.

For example, in listing template I can do

```
{% setcontent products = 'products_de' %}
```

But its get me contenttype records but not contenttype options. There is `'contenttype'` key in array `record`, but there is may not be any products, so I'll can't get it.

Is there any global methot to get contenttype options, something like config:

```
{{ config.get('general/sitename') }}
```

UPD: I am interested in the same for taxonomies - how to get taxonomy options such as name, slug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Contenttype data can be obtained with:

```
{{ config.get('contenttypes/pages') }}
```

Taxonomy data can be obtained with:

```
{{ config.get('taxonomy/categories') }}
```

So you can do just:

```
{% set products_data = config.get('contenttypes/products_de') %}
{{ products_data.name }}
{{ products_data.slug }}
```